# Federal Rules of Evidence 803-6 usage

Tags: united-states, rules-of-evidence

Is it possible for a document to be self-showing that it's a business document? For example, can you admit a business document (e.g. a packing slip) which clearly is implied that 1) the record must have been made with someone with the knowledge 2) the record was kept as part of a regularly conducted activity of a business and 3) making the record was part of the regularly conducted activity?

Federal Rules of Evidence ("FRE") 803-6 (d) explains that a custodian or qualified witness must show all three (FRE 803-6 a-c), but can a document just be obviously meeting the qualifications without testimony? For the sake of the question, I'm assuming there is no certification under FRE 902.

Comment: Please edit the question to provide the full name of the legislation as well as a jurisdiction tag. It's better not to assume that the reader knows what "803-6" and "902" mean.

Comment: FRE refers to the Federal Rules of Evidence! Thank you.

Comment: @seam That's still missing a jurisdiction. It might seem obvious to you that Federal Rules of Evidence refers to the US, but it isn't necessarily obvious to everyone else - this is an international site with many users from different jurisdictions.  Also, you should edit these details into the question rather than in the comments. You can use tags to provide jurisdiction. I've made an edit for you to reflect these points.

Comment: I'm pretty sure anyone with a helpful answer to provide has all the information necessary to do so.